# $C$ circuit and electrostatic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

My first question is either if there are capacitors in series/parallel or what does P mean in between them.

The second would be the amount of charges in them, once the difference in electrical potential between A/P and P/B is V, because.. once A and P are positive (I think?), there's no reason P would move as it does in 3

[image: in 1 the fonts are turned off, in two the capacitors get charged and in 3 the electrostatic energy is supposed to change]

Comment: do you mean the equivalent circuit?

Comment: @lineage yes, the representation, if it exists

Comment: whats fig 3? is that the solution?

Comment: @lineage no that's the final situation, P moves a distance $d$, I'm seeking to solve it later so I just wanted to understand what's going on with it, the question asks by what factor does the electrostatical energy stored in the capacitor changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent circuit of fig $1$ is two capacitor's $C_{AP},C_{PB}$ in series when $S_2$ is open. This is because the terminal $P$ can be split into two terminals $P_1,P_2$ connected to each other and to $S_{2}$. So the equivalent circuit would have the two capacitors $C_{AP_1},C_{P_2B}$ in series(when $S_2$) is open.

As to the charge when both $C_{AP},C_{PB}$ and have the same potential across them-you need to know the capacitances.

Assuming

1. ideal parallel plate capacitors
2. same plate area for both capacitors
3. equilibrium

$C=Q/V\propto 1/d$

where

$Q$ is the charge stored in the capacitor of capacitance $C$ with plate separation $d$ when potential across it is V.

So charge in $Q_{AP}<Q_{PB}$ as per fig 1.

Whats happening in fig 3 is that after charging the caps. have been disconnected and then the capacitances are being changed by moving P.